# How to mock System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString() with moq?

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit, moq, xmlwriter

When I run the following code in my test,

```
Mock<XmlWriter> mockXmlWriter = new Mock<System.Xml.XmlWriter>();
Language language = Language.GetLangauge(langId);
language.WriteXml(mockXmlWriter.Object);
mockXmlWriter.Verify(writer => writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", language.LanguageID.ToString()));
```

Moq understandably throws the following exception: `System.NotSupportedException : Invalid verify on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: writer => writer.WriteAttributeString("ID", .language.LanguageID.ToString())`.

Stupid abstract `XmlWriter` still has some non-abstract, non-virtual methods, like `WriteAttributeString()` :(

I looked for an `XmlWriterBase` or a `System.Xml.Abstractions`, like I do for `HttpContext` and Co., but found nothing :(

How would I overcome this so I can test that my `WriteXml` method is doing what it's supposed to be doing?

Comment: Have you tried creating a subclass, overriding the method, and marking it as virtual>

Comment: I did this and now `Verify()` is complaining that `WriteAttributeString()` never gets called. When I step through the code, it clearly is :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, it is a bad idea to mock out classes you don't own, since you do not have a full control over them and that can result in problems (such as yours).

I think you can safely use a real `XmlWriter` here that would write its output to a `MemoryStream` and that simply assert that the stream contains the expected XML:

```
// arrange
MemoryStream underlyingStream = new MemoryStream();
XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(underlyingStream);
Language language = Language.GetLangauge(langId);

// act
language.WriteXml(xmlWriter);

// assert
underlyingStream.Position = 0;
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(underlyingStream)
{
    string createdXml = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    Assert.That(createdXml, Is.EqualTo("expectedXml"));
}
```

The assertion part can be nicely refactored out to a helper method. Having recently written a code dealing with XML creating, I got burned on it pretty badly - at first, my tests were mock-based and essentialy, they were an exact copies of the production code. Fortunately, halfway through I've decided to refactor the whole thing to the style similar to one in my example and it really helped - tests are now much less fragile and everything is simpler.

Comment: I thought one of the primary uses of mocking was mokcing classes you don't own.

Comment: @mo. I got burned so many times when mocking 3rd party classes that now I think really hard before doing it. [This article](http://freshbrewedcode.com/derekgreer/2012/04/01/tdd-best-practices-dont-mock-others/) puts it together rather nicely. Also, if you can get your hands on [this wonderful book](http://www.amazon.com/Growing-Object-Oriented-Software-Guided-Tests/dp/0321503627), it has a whole chapter devoted to the issue.

Comment: @mo. Mocking is used for replacing dependencies that have side effects: things like file I/O, network traffic, database writes, and so on. The limitation, however, is that you can't mock static members (DateTime.Now), sealed classes (System.String), nor non-virtual members, as you're hitting now. I'd recommend against mocking 3rd party classes. If you have a dependency on a 3rd party object with side effects, then replace that dependency with an interface, and mock that.

Comment: How do you replace a 3rd party implementation with an interface? You mean replace it with an interface and an implementation that forms a very thin (so it doesn't need its own tests) wrapper around your 3rd party dependency?

Comment: @NikolaAnusev, your code above worked great, thanks. It feels, however, that the test is primarily concerned with testing Microsoft's XmlWriter, and also just happens to test my Language.WriteXml. Is this okay? Do we just accept it as the best we can do with the given situation?

Comment: @mo re. `"How do you replace a 3rd party implementation with an interface?"` If you need to mock the behavior of a dependency, what you said in your question sounds good. I.e. make an interface, mock the interface; then make an implementation of the interface that's just a very thin wrapper. That doesn't have to increase the risk, since you already have code calling the XmlWriter, it just wasn't  in a separate class before. The wrapper class might be a good candidate for some tests that call into the real XmlWriter if you want to also test the wrapper code.

Comment: @mo. Yes, you can indeed say both the `XmlWriter` and your `Language` class are tested with a single test. While I am sure this will be frowned upon by many TDD purists out there, I think it's a pragmatic thing to do here. Realistically speaking - is there a chance that `XmlWriter` contains a bug that would influence your tests in an unexpected way? I don't think so. On the other hand, if you do make use of it, I am sure your tests will be easier both to understand and mantain. In the end, though, do what you feel best about; you could also consider @Daryn's approach.